# Youtube video not visible in facebook tab

Tags: facebook, youtube

I am experiencing trouble in Facebook brand tab, for my client's Facebook page.

I have created a tab inside Facebook Page.
I have HTML code for the same.
In this code i have used iframe to showcase video from Youtube.
When i open this html file with google chrome from my desktop entire design of 810 x 800px is visible with 'youtube video' and video gets played.
but the moment I create a new tab inside Facebook page, give my app id and url only background image is visible and no video!

All my content comes from SSL certified site.

Here is the code i am using.

```
enter code here
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD html 4.01//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> 
<meta name="language" content="english">  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css"> 

<title>Kich Video</title> 

<style type="text/css"> 
body { 
margin:0; 
background-color:#f0f0f0; 
 } 
#container {
width:810px;
height:695px;
padding-top:115px;
padding-left:260px;
margin:0px;
background-image:url(https://spotlightcommunication.com/work/kichtvad/background.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
 } 
#container object { 
width:560px; 
height:315px; 
 } 
</style> 

</head> 
<body style="margin:0"> 

<div id="container"> 

<iframe width="500" height="281" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/4CjayX3GNmU?rel=0"  
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>
<div style="padding-left:0px;"> 
<a href="http://www.crowdmultiplier.com"><img   
src="http://i1160.photobucket.com/albums/q495/chandansolanki/CMPowered810x60_Px.jpg"></a></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

I have currently keep this tab alive on Facebook page.
there you can see, only background image is visible and not video.

Facebook page link  [Facebook](http://wwww.facebook.com/kichindia/).
Tab marked as Kich TV Ad needs to show this video.

Can anyone help me on this?

Kirit JAsani

Answer (score 0):

> All my content comes from SSL certified site.

Well, you always need to use https. If you take a look in the Browser console, it will tell you that the youtube link got blocked because it´s unsafe content (http instead of https). Use https for ALL absolute URLs. That goes for the youtube src and for the photobucket src.

Comment: glad i could help. please accept my answer if you can :)